# Geoserver WMTS Service REST url

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector, arcgis-rest-api, wmts

recently I have installed the Geoserver with vector tile layer extension, getting the data in pbf (Mapbox vector tile format).

> `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=VectorTileLayer:tbl__analysis&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/json;type=geojson&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}`

I want to convert this request URL to RESTfull like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/1.0.0/blocks/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf
```

I have tried many methods but none of them working

My goal is to get the data in RESTful link for vector tiles .pbf layer

### Update..

#### Logical reply in the question.

`Geoserver currently doesn't support any restful service for URL mapping for wmts.`

Comment: Documentation in http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/wmts.html says "GeoWebCache fully implements WMTS using KVP, and is seeking funding for the RESTful and SOAP based approaches."  The approach would be to implement RESTful access by your own coding or by funding it.

Comment: i want to use wmts layer in mapbox gl library i don't know what approach should i follow to publish vector tile layer

Comment: If GeoServer WMTS does not work with REST requests and MapBox GL can't make KVP requests then you have a problem. Perhaps using TMS instead of WMTS could be a solution http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html.

Comment: URL templating has nothing to do with REST. For REST you need hypermedia formats, the client has no knowledge of the API, only the hypermedia.

Answer (score 3):

To use mapbox vector tiles served by GeoServer, you can do it like this:

```
// First the layer URL pattern
var layerWMTS = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=public:list_parcels_hobart_4326&tilematrixset=EPSG:900913&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector&TileMatrix=EPSG:900913:{z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}'

// Now add the layer
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'geoserver',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': {
    'type': 'vector',
    'tiles': [
      layerWMTS
    ]
  },
  'layout': {
    'visibility': 'visible'
  },
  'source-layer': 'list_parcels_hobart_4326',
  'paint': {
    'fill-color': 'rgba(244, 131, 66, 0.4)',
    'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(244, 131, 66, 0.9)'
  }
})
```

This is about as simple as it gets. Note that some of the keywords need to be changed, soch as the `layer=public:list_parcels_hobart_4326` section of the layer URL, and the `'source-layer': 'list_parcels_hobart_4326'` of the layer parameter object. These can be taken from what you have configured in GeoServer.

And just a note to say that I think that GeoServer's vector tiles are pretty good, but it doesn't seem configurable, so you can't change simplification and such. I have a bit of [exploration over here](https://github.com/alexgleith/geoserver-vector-tiles-testing/), although it's probably not well documented and a bit messy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that can help you:
https://github.com/PDOK/wmts-kvp-to-restful